# Manually passing a value to a generator yields unexpected results with jest tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generator, jestjs

I have the following redux saga, which makes an api call and processes the results:

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { normalize, arrayOf } from 'normalizr'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as schemas from './schemas'
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import { api, constants as apiConstants } from '../../services/api'

export function* fetchWorks() {
  const { response, error } = yield call(api.getJson, apiConstants.WORKS_ENDPOINT)
  if (response) {
    const normalized = normalize(response.items, arrayOf(schemas.works))
    yield put(actions.fetchWorksSuccess(normalized))
  } else {
    yield put(actions.fetchWorksFail(error))
  }
}
```

I'm testing whether everything works with these jest tests:

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import * as sagas from './sagas'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import { api, constants as apiConstants } from '../../services/api'

describe('works saga', () => {
  describe('fetchWorks', () => {
    it('should fetch data', () => {
      const generator = sagas.fetchWorks()
      const actual = generator.next().value
      const expected = call(api.getJson, apiConstants.WORKS_ENDPOINT)
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
    })

    // this test requires me to pass a response object to the generator
    it('should put fetchWorksSuccess on a response', () => {
      // so I create it here
      const response = {
        items: [{
          sys: { id: '1' },
          fields: { content: 'content' }
        }]
      }
      const generator = sagas.fetchWorks()
      const expected = put(actions.fetchWorksSuccess())
      // but I would expect to pass it here    
      generator.next()
      // but actually the test only succeeds if I pass it here
      const actual = generator.next({ response }).value
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
    })

    // same goes for this test
    it('should put fetchWorksFail on errors', () => {
      const error = new Error('Something went wrong')
      const generator = sagas.fetchWorks()
      const expected = put(actions.fetchWorksFail())
      generator.next()
      const actual = generator.next({ error }).value
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
    })
  })
})
```

However, for the `'should put fetchWorksSuccess on a response'` and `'should put fetchWorksFail on errors'` tests, I have to manually pass a `{response}` and `{error}` object into each generator respectively.

I understand that these objects are necessary (because of the if statement that checks if there is a response), but I don't understand why I have to pass it to the second `.next()` instead of the first? Because the way I see it the first `yield` yields the response or error object, not the second one. Does anyone understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a React thing, it's a generator thing.

The first call to `generator.next()` starts the generator, not returns from the yield call:

```
>>> function *example_generator() {
  console.log('before first yield', Array.slice(arguments));
  var first_yield = yield 'first';
  console.log('first yield returned', first_yield);
  var second_yield = yield 'second';
  console.log('second yield returned', second_yield);
  return 'done';
}
>>> generator = example_generator("generator", "creation")
Generator {}
>>> generator.next("first next")
before first yield  Array [ "generator", "creation" ]
Object { value: "first", done: false }
>>> generator.next("second next")
first yield returned second next
Object { value: "second", done: false }
>>> generator.next("third next")
second yield returned third next
Object { value: "done", done: true }
```

Your initial call to `fetchWorks()` creates the generator object, but doesn't actually start the generator.

Think about it this way - the first call to `next()` gives you the value passed to the first `yield`; the argument given the second call to `next()` lets you specify the return value of the first `yield`.

Comment: Ah ok. The MDN docs didn't really help me to understand that. Your answer, combined with this article (https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators) and experimenting on codepen (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNbRpe?editors=0010) helped me understand it. Thanks!